# VSCode: Jump to the end of line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to jump to the end of a specific line.

When pressing `ctrl/cmd + p`, typing ":10" and hitting enter, I'm taken to line 10. Is there some setting or way to automatically go to the end of the line without having to use the `End` key?

Comment: Logical EOL? Physical EOL?

Comment: Physical but either will work for me

Comment: This can be done with a macro but I have never been successfulat overriding the `enter` key for a custom keybinding.  Would you like to see the macro that you could set for your own, non-enter key, keybinding?  Like `Alt+Right` for example.

Comment: Sure. If you post the macro I can go from there.

Answer (score 2):

Using some macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) or another you need this in your settings:

```
 "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.gotoEndOfLine",
      "sequence": [
        "workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem",
        "cursorEnd",
      ]
    }
 }
```

and some keybinding (in keybindings.json):

```
{
  "key": "alt+right",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.gotoEndOfLine" },
  "when": "inQuickOpen"
},
```

I could not get it to work with <kbd>Enter</kbd> or something using `Enter`, like Shift+Enter - perhaps some conflict I couldn't figure out.

[image: cursor macro]

In the demo I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open the QuickInput straight to the goto line functionality but it doesn't matter how you get there.  Then trigger the macro with your chosen keybinding.